# How do I return an exception message to the service to the user?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What I want to do is, when an exception occurs in the service, I want to pass the message I wrote to the controller and send it to the user along with http status 400. What should I do?

Service:

```
    public List<GoodsDto> getSubCategoryGoodsList(Long mainCategoryId, Long subCategoryId){
            MainCategory mainCategory = mainCategoryRepository.findById(mainCategoryId)
                                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("This category does not exist"));
            SubCategory subCategory = subCategoryRepository.findById(subCategoryId)
                                    .orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalArgumentException("This category does not exist"));
    
            List<Goods> goodsList = goodsRepository.findAllByMainCategoryAndSubCategory(mainCategory,subCategory);
            List<GoodsDto> goodsDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Goods goods : goodsList){
                GoodsDto goodsDto = new GoodsDto(goods);
                goodsDtoList.add(goodsDto);
            }
            return goodsDtoList;
        }
```

Controller:

```
      @GetMapping("/api/v1/main-category/{mainCategoryId}/sub-category/{subCategoryId}/goods")
      public ResponseEntity<Object> getSubCategoryGoodsList(@PathVariable Long mainCategoryId, @PathVariable Long subCategoryId){
            List<GoodsDto> goodsDtoList = goodsService.getSubCategoryGoodsList(mainCategoryId,subCategoryId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(goodsDtoList, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

Comment: What response you are getting currently if the API fails ?

Comment: You can add error handlers for your exceptions https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring